# How to recover Micro SD, accidentally quick-formatted + 4 files copies onto it

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, sd-card

I just accidentally quick formatted a micro SD card, with about 8 GB of pictures on it. I didn't know it was plugged in, and I meant to format something else.  Worse, I copied 4 files onto it, totaling about 500MB - permanently destroying what was there.

It was FAT32, and was formatted to that.

How do I go about recovering whatever I can?

Comment: Try [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).  It has worked for me in the past and is free.  If it saves your a**.. I myself would consider donating something to the author.

Comment: I ran Recuva.  It recovered 540 files. At least that's something. So many pictures / videos were overwritten/unrecoverable.  I will try testdisk tomorrow.  Recuva only recovers files that aren't overwritten at all. Maybe some partials will be worth something.

Comment: Photorec did a much better job.  I wonder why Google doesn't put Photorec higher is the results for data recovery.

Comment: By testdisk.. I knew you would look around and see photorec too.  Google cares nothing for "better".. Recuva is a paid product and "somehow" gets higher results.. hrrmmm..  ;).  BTW, the photorec/testdisk dude is an amazing programmer.